# List Zip method identifies series as index

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, python-zip

I have created tuples before like this:

```
list(zip(df['Column1'],df['Column2']))
```

But when I do this, it doesn't work.

```
    Lane    Carrier Scac    Cust Linehaul_2022Q2    Cust Linehaul_2022Q3    Cust Linehaul_2022Q4    Load Number_2022Q2  Load Number_2022Q3  Load Number_2022Q4
0   ADELANTO, CA - BLOOMINGTON, CA  RDWY    0.0 105.9   0.0 0   1   0
1   ALACHUA, FL - LITHIA SPRINGS, GA    MGXB    0.0 1603.0  0.0 0   1   0
2   ALACHUA, FL - LITHIA SPRINGS, GA    RDWY    101.3   105.1   0.0 1   1   0

list(zip(df_SO['Cust Linehaul_2022Q2'],df_SO['Cust Linehaul_2022Q3']))

TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

I learnt that way to make a tuple from this thread:
[How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel/1663826#1663826)

But not sure why this one is identifying as an index and not a series.

Comment: The likely problem here is that you created your own variable called `list` which is of type `Index`.  This is why we advise over and over and over not to create variables with names that echo the Python types.

Comment: Indeed it was left hanging there. Sorry for that. Thanks.